# Having trouble converting a whole sentence from uppercase to lower case in C

Tags: c

My code is correct as I can see it has no errors at all, but when I execute it and say for instance I type in "MY NAME IS JACK" it only converts "MY" to lowercase.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<string.h>

int main()

{

char str[20];

int i;

  printf("Enter any string->");

  scanf("%s",&str);

  for(i=0;i<=strlen(str);i++){


      if(str[i]>=65&&str[i]<=90)

       str[i]=str[i]+32;

  }

  printf("\nThe string in lower case is->%s",str);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, my phone is buggy... Nevertheless here the issue is not with your naive lowercase conversion, but with `scanf` that reads only one word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, `scanf` using the `%s` conversion specifier will stop reading intput at the first whitespace character.  If you want to read in the whole line, use `fgets` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
...
if ( fgets( str, sizeof str, stdin ) != NULL )
{
  /**
   * chop off the newline if it's present
   */
  char *newline = strchr( str, '\n' );
  if ( newline )
  {
    *newline = 0;
  }

  /**
   * Convert the string to lower case.
   */
  for ( int i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++ )
    str[i] = tolower( str[i] );
}
```

Note - if there isn't a newline in the buffer, that means that the user typed in a string that was longer than the buffer could hold, meaning there's leftover data in the input stream.  You'll probably want to issue a warning and consume that leftover input (usually by repeatedly calling `fgets` or `getchar` and stopping when you see a newline character).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I recognized that I had to use fgets. Silly error.

Answer (score 1):

The [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) description for the `%s` format defines it as:

> Any number of non-whitespace characters, stopping at the first whitespace character found. A terminating null character is automatically added at the end of the stored sequence.

So you are asking for the first non-whitespace text within `str`, which is "MY". Once it hits that space, it stops.

What would be better for your usage: reading the entire line in at once, or putting your `scanf` into a loop so you can read successive words?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code for it as well once you are done with your input.

```
void convertToUpperCase(char *sPtr)
{
  while(*sPtr != '\0')
  {
     if (islower(*sPtr))
          *sPtr = toupper(*sPtr);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First,

`scanf()` expects argument of type 'char *' but you are passing char (*)[20]. Just pass 'str'.

Second,

This is just suggestion. Try to use `isalpha()` or `issuper()`, `islower()`

Comment: Yea thanks for the suggestion but I'm trying to write the code using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
scanf("%s",&str);
```

to

```
scanf("%[^\n]",str);
```

and your code should work. `%s` reads until whitespaces. Using `[^\n]` makes scanf read into the str variable until it encounters a newline. Also, don't pass the address of `str`, just `str` itself.

Comment: What I did was I used fgets(str,20,stdin) and it worked fine but thank you very much!